LT spice, JK Flip Flop: Wrong behaviour when J K and Clock are high
Here's a picture of a JK Flip Flop I try to simulate with NAND gates:

This is the behavior I would expect; if Clk, J and K are all high, Q_n+1 should be negated Q_n:

However this is what I'm observing:

Notice that around 30ms CLK, K, and J are all high. However Q and Q' are both one, which would imply it's an invalid state.
Furthermore the previous state of Q was also 1 so it's not even negated.
Could someone explain whats going on?

Edit: Since the up arrow in the truthtable denotes a switch from low to high, I also implemented that case:


Did you worry about delays ?

Where's your CLK signal shown?

I've added the clock, and I also redid the simulation for s instead of ms and the behaviour stays the same.

In the truth table, what do you understand the up-arrow to mean in the CLK column?

I have the impression, looking at the drawn circuit, that the difference between Latch and flip-flop is not known!!!

Let's take a quick refresher on logic devices by carefully observing the following drawings (The drawings were created by me using Windows Paint):

Calculation of the characteristic equation of the flip-flop under consideration:


I'm just learning about flip-flops and I followed along with this video specifically, from where I got the circuit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6krFp511HA. Also, if you google JK flip-flop, a lot of circuits come up identical to mine. If you're implying that I don't know my circuits, then there seem to be a lot of resources wrong too.

@haifisch123 I have taught, among other subjects, digital electronics for many years, and I assure you that is a latch and not a flip-flop. You should get a good digital electronics textbook and you will see who is right.

@haifisch123  That video series, although generally very good (in my opinion), does confuse up a bunch of terminology when dealing with latches vs flip-flops, level triggering vs edge triggering, clock vs enable etc.  It's not unique to that video, but it's also all over the place.

This topic is a bit nuanced and the terminology is kind of all over the place.  According to the terminology highlighted in this answer from a previous question, the schematic you drew up is that of a "gated JK latch".  In a comment from another answer, you linked to this video introducing the circuit you drew.  A couple videos later in the series, the instructor explains that there is a problem with this circuit when in the "toggle" state.  In the video after that, he explains how to use two gated JK latches to form an actual JK flip-flop (using a master-slave topology) to fix this problem.

Getting back to your original problem (circuit not simulating as intended), you seem to be using 3rd party 74HCT library NAND gates (possibly from the LTspice Google Groups???).  For these kind of academic exercises, I think it's better to use the built-in Digital parts found within LTspice.  However, you have to configure them correctly.  In this topology, I found that you must set initial conditions on \$Q\$ and \$\overline{Q}\$ (see .ic V(Q)=5 V(_Q)=0) and that the propagation delay of the left gates must be greater than the right gates (see td=10n vs td=10p).  Below is my version of your simulation (with some modified timings), and it seems like it's operating correctly as a gated JK latch.  You can even see the "race around condition" described in the video when all three inputs are high.  It's possible your 74HCT simulation is not working correctly because the left versus right gates have propagation delays which are too similar.



Below is my LTspice .asc schematic file as text.  Copy/paste it into a text file, name it with a .asc extension, and open it in LTspice to play around with the circuit.
Version 4
SHEET 1 1152 696
WIRE -224 -32 -256 -32
WIRE -256 16 -256 -32
WIRE 816 64 64 64
WIRE -256 128 -256 96
WIRE 64 128 64 64
WIRE 160 128 64 128
WIRE 160 144 0 144
WIRE 160 160 64 160
WIRE 592 160 224 160
WIRE 592 192 496 192
WIRE 752 192 656 192
WIRE 784 192 752 192
WIRE 864 192 784 192
WIRE -224 240 -256 240
WIRE 496 256 496 192
WIRE 752 256 752 192
WIRE -256 288 -256 240
WIRE 64 288 64 160
WIRE 64 288 0 288
WIRE 496 352 752 256
WIRE 752 352 496 256
WIRE -256 400 -256 368
WIRE 64 400 64 288
WIRE 160 400 64 400
WIRE 496 400 496 352
WIRE 592 400 496 400
WIRE 160 416 0 416
WIRE 160 432 64 432
WIRE 592 432 224 432
WIRE 752 432 752 352
WIRE 752 432 656 432
WIRE 816 432 816 64
WIRE 816 432 752 432
WIRE 864 432 816 432
WIRE -224 496 -256 496
WIRE 64 528 64 432
WIRE 784 528 784 192
WIRE 784 528 64 528
WIRE -256 544 -256 496
WIRE -256 656 -256 624
FLAG -256 128 0
FLAG -224 -32 J
FLAG 0 144 J
FLAG 0 416 K
FLAG 864 192 Q
FLAG 864 432 _Q
FLAG -256 656 0
FLAG -224 496 K
FLAG -256 400 0
FLAG -224 240 CLK
FLAG 0 288 CLK
SYMBOL Digital\\and 192 80 R0
WINDOW 3 -105 117 Left 1
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMATTR Value vhigh=5 td=10n tau=10p
SYMBOL Digital\\and 192 352 R0
WINDOW 3 -105 117 Left 1
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMATTR Value vhigh=5 td=10n tau=10p
SYMBOL Digital\\and 624 112 R0
WINDOW 3 -106 115 Left 1
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMATTR Value vhigh=5 td=10p tau=10p
SYMBOL Digital\\and 624 352 R0
WINDOW 3 -104 117 Left 1
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMATTR Value vhigh=5 td=10p tau=10p
SYMBOL voltage -256 0 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 200n 10p 10p 200n 400n)
SYMBOL voltage -256 528 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 200n 10p 10p 100n 200n)
SYMBOL voltage -256 272 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 5
TEXT 332 584 Left 2 !.tran 1u
TEXT 280 624 Left 2 !.ic V(Q)=5 V(_Q)=0

